# How to end a for loop that goes through a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

I'm having trouble ending my `for` loop.  It just continues even when it appears it should be done.

It goes through a set of pointer arrays and when the last pointer is returned `NULL` it should end.  But it continues on.  I feel as though I'm missing something rather simple.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
#include "shape.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

shape *getShape();

int main(){    
    shape *shape[10];

    for(int idx = 0; shape[idx] != NULL; ++idx)
    {    
        shape[idx] = getShape();         
    }

cout << "you made it!";    
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: you are confusing C and c++.

Comment: What does `getShape` do? does it ever return `NULL` ?

Comment: The `for()` loop doesn't know the size of `shape[]` is 10, it just keeps going until it finds a `NULL`, if you don't put one there it won't just magically spawn by itself. C strings are null-terminated, arrays aren't.

Comment: show the function for getShape();

Answer (score 0):

The condition is evaluated before each run, so the first few parts of the code expand out to be:

```
int idx = 0 ;
while ( 1 )
{
    if ( shape[idx] == NULL ) break ;
    shape[idx] = getShape() ;
    ++idx ;
    if ( shape[idx] == NULL ) break ;
    shape[idx] = getShape() ;
    ++idx ;
    // and so on
}
```

I'm assuming you're trying to run until `getShape` returns NULL, so try this:

```
int idx = -1 ;
do
{
    shape[++idx] = getShape() ;
} while ( shape[idx] != NULL ) ;
```

Also note that I'm assuming additional checks were omitted from your example for sample purposes, but I'll mention just in case that you should **always always always** check the the end of your C-Array as well so you don't stomp on memory that falls after your allocated array segment.

**Edit**

Here're the additional checks I'm talking about in a more complete code example:

```
enum {
    kArraySize = 10
} ;
shape* shapes[kArraySize] ; // note: named it "shapes" instead of "shape" to avoid a name collision
int idx = -1 ;
do
{
    ++idx ; // *prepare* to go to the next index
    if ( idx >= kArraySize ) // only need ==, but >= gives extra safety
        break ; // stop before we go past the end of the array!
    shapes[idx] = getShape() ;
} while ( shapes[idx] != NULL ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you iAdjunct!  This did it.  You were correct and I see now I probably could have added more info but this was done in a rush.

You were correct about getShape returning NULL when it was finished with it's job.  But I couldn't figure out how to end the loop through that.  The above is working as expected.

It looks like I was confusing my syntax.  I had previously tried a while loop but it did not work as expect and it was because I was no using do correctly.

Comment: Can you please expand on the checking of an Array?  Being new to this I'm not familiar with that.  I would have liked to make this a dynamically created array but wasn't too sure on that either or if it's needed.  But I imagine if I did that I would not need to check it as it may be built into the dynamic creation?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop can be simplified to...

```
for(int idx = 0; idx<10 && (shape[idx]=getShape()) != NULL; ++idx);
```

You can assign and compare in the same statement.

You may want to dynamically figure out the size of the array, as other answers have suggested. I've just hard-coded 10 for simplicity.

For this particular example, it would be best to simply declare a constant to define the array, and then use this constant in the for loop condition.

Answer (score -1):

It's not sure, if shape[10] is NULL. It could have some content, which has not been removed.

Try this:

```
shape *shape[n];

int lng = sizeof(shape)/sizeof(shape);

for(int idx = 0; idx < lng; ++idx)
{
  shape[idx] = getShape();
}
```

Comment: `shape[10]` does not exist, the valid indices are 0 through 9

Comment: Sure shape[10] exists! He never says "stop if i == 9" and he could overflow the array. You can never be sure, that the memory space is NULL...

Comment: array of bound `10` only has elements `0` through `9`